# Convert a string to Date Format using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a date(string) value in an XML file in this format:

> 2012-09-21T19:15:00Z

I want to use XSL transformation to convert the string/date into this format:

> 07:15 PM

I am using this XSL

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($date, '[h]:[m01] [PN]', 'en', (), ())"/>
```

But I'm getting it as 7:15 P.M. and I need it as 7:15 PM

How do I get it in the format I want?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($date, '[h]:[m01] [PN]', 'en', (), ())"/>`
I'm getting it as `7:15 P.M.`, but i need it as `7:15 PM`

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've shown what code you're working with it's clear you're nearly there. It seems you simply want to remove the dots in "P.M.". In which case:

```
translate(format-dateTime($date, '[h]:[m01] [PN]', 'en', (), ()), '.', '')
```

That replaces ("translates", in XSLT terminology) each full-stop with nothing, i.e. removes them.

Point of note: `format-date` is XSLT 2 only, whereas your question is tagged XSLT 1.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting the same..
and sorry for tagging it wrongly, since i am new to xslt..

Comment: @Utkannos...here also i've a problem...the output i get is `7:15 PM` right.. but i need it as `07:15 PM`